# TAB in Emacs doesn't work properly

Tags: key-bindings

My tab key in emacs behaves as follows:
Instead of inserting a tab, it now removes all leading spaces of the line:

`Test Line`

After pressing the tab key at any position of the line:

`Test Line`

Does someone know which option i have to change to get the regular behavior?

Comment: What major mode are you in? Pressing `C-q TAB` should insert the literal tab, anyway.

Comment: Yes ```C-q TAB``` works, I am in emacs-lisp-mode

Comment: Does it happen from `emacs -Q` as well?

Comment: You can use `C-h k TAB` to get help on the command associated to TAB.

Comment: Yes same behavior when i start emacs -Q.

Comment: As you are new here, I am assuming you are just starting with Emacs(-lisp). So you have only this single line in your file? Because then I would say that auto-indenting is the regular behavior, and so removing all leading spaces is regular behavior here. Why you would like to indent? I would say, generally, it is recommended to let Emacs take care of indentation in `emacs-lisp-mode` (i.e. generally there is no need to manually add tabs in `emacs-lisp-mode`). For example, copy some lisp code to the buffer, then select all of it and see how Emacs auto indents it.

Comment: Same question (but can't delete as duplicate because no upvoted answer): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/59978/105.

Comment: That is the correct behavior for TAB in `emacs-lisp-mode`. If you just want to write free-form text try `text-mode` or `fundamental-mode`.